# Entering a four digit number using buttons in plotly dash

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I want to enter values for a four digit number using a keypad input in Plotly Dash i.e. enter 2 and number displayed is 2, then enter 3 and number displayed is 23.

The below technically should achieve this:

```
import dash
import dash_daq as daq
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Button(id='button-7', value='7', children='7', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'}),
        html.Button(id='button-8', value='8', children='8', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'}),
        html.Button(id='button-9', value='9', children='9', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'})
    ], style={'display': 'flex'}),
    html.Div([
        html.Button(id='button-4', value='4', children='4', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'}),
        html.Button(id='button-5', value='5', children='5', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'}),
        html.Button(id='button-6', value='6', children='6', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'})
    ], style={'display': 'flex'}),
    html.Div([
        html.Button(id='button-1', value='1', children='1', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'}),
        html.Button(id='button-2', value='2', children='2', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'}),
        html.Button(id='button-3', value='3', children='3', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'})
    ], style={'display': 'flex'}),
    html.Div([
        html.Button(id='button-0', value='0', children='0', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'}),
        html.Button('Reset', id='button-reset', style={'fontSize':24, 'width': '33%', 'height': '60px'}),
    ], style={'display': 'flex'}),
    html.Div([
        html.Output(id='output', children='', style={'fontSize':48, 'width': '100%', 'height': '60px'})
    ], style={'display': 'flex'})
])

@app.callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    [Input('button-1', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-2', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-3', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-4', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-5', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-6', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-7', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-8', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-9', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('button-0', 'n_clicks'), 
     State('output', 'children')])
def display_output(*n_clicks):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    if not ctx.triggered:
        return ''
    else:
        button_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
        button_value = button_id.split('-')[-1]
        output_value = ctx.inputs['output.children'] + button_value if len(ctx.inputs['output.children']) < 4 else ctx.inputs['output.children']
        return output_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

But it is throwing an error:

> output_value = ctx.inputs['output.children'] + button_value if
> len(ctx.inputs['output.children']) < 4 else
> ctx.inputs['output.children'] KeyError: 'output.children'

Essentially I want 'output.children' to be the previous state pre button press, but I can't work out how to save that and use it within the output_value statement in the function. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved this by introducing a dcc.Store element to store the previous entered values, and then returning data from that in the call back